# Is this Molinia litoralis or any other Molinia?

Tags: identification

Would you help me identify this grass in Central Europe?

[image: a]

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the plant with the pinkish seedheads in the center of the photo, then no, I don't think so. Molina tends to have long stems and is considered a "see-through" plant. Very elegant, and very attractive with dew on it in the morning, with the sun behind it.

FWIW, I don't recognize the pinkish plant, but I really like it.